# Getting started with Stack Apps

Tags: support, stackapps, tutorials

I am new to [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/about), so need help in getting started:

1. A tutorial on Stack Apps.
2. What languages I need to learn to get started with Stack Apps.
3. List of apps in Stack Apps.

Answer (score 8):

This is pretty much all on StackApps itself. There isn't exactly a tutorial, but there's [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), a [Hello World app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/api-hello-world-code), and a [Sample app](https://stackapps.com/questions/3/sample-application-worlds-worst-stackoverflow-clone) you can read through (the apps use the 1.1 API though). You can use any language, as long as it's capable of communicating with the API interface; if you want to use a library you'll need to choose [one of the languages that has one](https://stackapps.com/questions/288/list-of-api-client-libraries-grouped-by-programming-language). The list of apps is available on the homepage, in the [apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) tab